# compare two column of a tableand if not matched then update in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table test5.having 10000 records.there is two column in table called es_id and cac_id.I want to make these column exact match.if its not macthed the update cac_is with es_id.

for example:

table **`test5`**

```
es_id      cac_id
xxx         xxx
yyy         yyy
zzz         abc
ddd         null
bbb         zzz
```

output should be :

```
es_id      cac_id
xxx        xxx
yyy        yyy
zzz        zzz
ddd        ddd
bbb        bbb
```

test5 table has 100000 records so update the table manually is vary deficult.Please suggest the better way to do this.

Please assist.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
UPDATE test5
SET es_id = CASE WHEN es_id IS NULL THEN cac_id 
                 ELSE es_id END,
    cac_id = CASE WHEN cac_id <> es_id OR cac_id IS NULL THEN es_id
                  ELSE cac_id END
WHERE cac_id <> es_id
  OR cac_id IS NULL
  OR es_id IS NULL;
```

This assumes that when es_id is null, cac_id is not, and the other way around

<kbd>[sqlfiddl demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a5d9/1)</kbd>

Comment: no its not work for null records...there is multiple null records in the table

Comment: @user2862073. I added the validation for when cac_id can be null. Can es_id ever be null?

Comment: awesome...suppose if its from two tables then? for example es_id from table test2 and cac_id from table test5 then how we can update test5.cac_id with test2.es_id...then what is the best approach?

Comment: For two tables and without any additional identifier that matches the two records, is impossible to do. There's no way to know which row from table2 matches on table5

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
UPDATE test5
   SET cac_id = es_id;
```

100K records isn't all that much, and you want them all the same anyway, so why check for the condition?  Assuming this isn't a recurring process, of course.

Comment: suppose if its from two tables then? for example es_id from table test2 and cac_id from table test5 then how we can update test5.cac_id with test2.es_id...then what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
    update table
    set es_id =cac_id OR cac_id=es_id
where es_id <> cac_id
```